# Which collation should I use when my entire application goes for UTF-8?

Tags: mysql, collation

I'm using MySQL, latest version. By default I get *latin1_swedish_ci* which doesn't sound really correct.

Comment: Depends on the locale really. The reason that different collation options exist is that different countries have different ideas of the sorting order of strings. So obviously use whichever collation makes sense for your language/culture/locale.

Comment: On a site that's translated into 20 languages? ...hard...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `utf8_general_ci`

Here is [a full list of the character sets and their descriptions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-charsets.html) from the MySQL reference site.

Comment: utf8_general_ci is the way to go. You will want to convert all your tables into utf8, this is the best collation to use in general.

If you have any columns which store non human-readable stuff which needs to be case sensitive (e.g. URLs), then make them utf8_binary

Answer (score 2):

You can change the default collation from the MySQL database configuration files.

Also see this link http://streetsmartingit.blogspot.com/2008/04/how-to-changeconvert-your-mysql.html for instructions on doing it with an existing database.